# "I hate swarms"

Tags: feature-request, design, answer-swarm

Some people like hats. Some people don't like hats. Some people *hate* hats. For this reason, hats could be hidden by the hat haters. Can a similar facility be provided for those that hate swarms?

Comment: [You and me both.](http://meta.arqade.com/q/7001/4797)

Answer (score 1):

As a mitigating ad-interim shitty solution you can click on the mobile link in the footer. That'll switch you to the unbranded, lazer-less mobile theme. The upshot is it'll work in any browser.

Comment: Alternatively, block answerswarm.com in Noscript.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Won't that result in no styles at all?

Comment: @fredley Actually, no. Noscript doesn't block CSS, just JS and assorted sundry.